# RuntimeError on windows trying python multiprocessing

Tags: python, windows, multithreading, multiprocessing, kaggle

I'm going to dump the error code I got while try a python script :

Preprocess validation data upfront

Using gpu device 0: Tesla K20c

`Traceback (most recent call last):`

`File "<string>", line 1, in <module>`

`File "C:\SciSoft\WinPython-64bit-2.7.6.4\python-2.7.6.amd64\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 380, in main
    prepare(preparation_data)`

`File "C:\SciSoft\WinPython-64bit-2.7.6.4\python-2.7.6.amd64\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 495, in prepare
    '__parents_main__', file, path_name, etc`

`File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Galaxy Data\kaggle-galaxies-master\kaggle-galaxies-master\try_convnet_cc_multirotflip_3x69r45_maxout2048_extradense.py", line 133, in <module>`

`for data, length in create_valid_gen():`

`File "load_data.py", line 572, in buffered_gen_mp
    process.start()`

`File "C:\SciSoft\WinPython-64bit-2.7.6.4\python-2.7.6.amd64\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 130, in start
    self._popen = Popen(self)

File "C:\SciSoft\WinPython-64bit-2.7.6.4\python-2.7.6.amd64\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 258, in **init**
    cmd = get_command_line() + [rhandle]

File "C:\SciSoft\WinPython-64bit-2.7.6.4\python-2.7.6.amd64\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 358, in get_command_line`

```
is not going to be frozen to produce a Windows executable.''')
```

RuntimeError: 
            Attempt to start a new process before the current process
            has finished its bootstrapping phase.

```
        This probably means that you are on Windows and you have
        forgotten to use the proper idiom in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce a Windows executable.
```

As I understand I have to insert a line

`if __name__ == '__main__':`

Some where to get it to work

Can anyone tell me in which File I should insert it ? I have included the affected files list in the initial error logs

The affected file :

https://github.com/benanne/kaggle-galaxies/blob/master/try_convnet_cc_multirotflip_3x69r45_maxout2048_extradense.py

Lines 131-134

and

https://github.com/benanne/kaggle-galaxies/blob/master/load_data.py

line 572

Comment: Could you show us your code?

Comment: Yes provided links to files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing#windows) is quite clear in this case.
The important part is `Safe importing of main module`.

Your `try_convnet_cc_multirotflip_3x69r45_maxout2048_extradense.py` script is doing lots of things on module level. Without reading it in details I can already say that you should wrap the workflow with a function and use it like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support() # Optional under circumstances described in docs
    your_workflow_function()
```

Besides the problem you have, it's a good habit not to surprise possible user of your script with side effects, if the user just wants to import it and reuse some of it's functionality.
So **don't** put your code on module level. It's ok to have constants on module level but the workflow should be in functions and classes.
If Python module is intended to be used as a script (like in your case), you simply put the `if __name__ == '__main__'` in the very end of this module, calling `your_workflow_function()` only if the module is the entry point for the interpreter - so called `main module`.